# Операция внутри функции

Tags: jquery

Приветcтвую вaс, каким образом в примере ниже, можно сделать так чтобы операция срабатывала только тогда, когда жмешь на **"page-1"**

```js
$('.page-1, .page-2, .page-3, .page-4').on('click',  function() {

$(this).toggleClass('open');
$(this).css({'z-index':'100'});

setTimeout(function() {$('.text-1').toggleClass('nado'); },  250); 
/* надо чтобы эта операция (toggleClass "nado") работала только тогда, 
когда пользователь кликает на класс ".page-1" */

});
```

```css
.page-1,
.page-2,
.page-3,
.page-4{
width: 250px;
height: 300px;
margin:30px;
position: relative;
border: 0.4vmax solid white;
border-radius: 0.3em;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
display: inline-block;
}

.text{
position: relative;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px; 
}

.text-1{
position: relative;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;

}


a{
text-decoration: none; 
color:black;
}



.nado{
border:3px solid black;
font-size: 30px;
transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-1" >
<div class="text-1">
<a href="#">Блок 1</a>
</div>
</div>
  
<div class="page-2" >
<div class="text">
<a href="#">Блок 2</a>
</div>
</div>
    
<div class="page-3" >
<div class="text">
<a href="#">Блок 3</a>
</div>
</div>
   
<div class="page-4" >
<div class="text">
<a href="#">Блок 4</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно добавить проверку

```
if($(this).hasClass( "page-1" )){
  setTimeout(function() {$('.text-1').toggleClass('nado'); },  250);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь сударь)))
А какие еще есть методы)?

Comment: тогда по конкретнее